# Homebrew install gdb, symlink error with binutils

Tags: macos, installation, symbolic-link, homebrew, gdb

I'm trying to install GDB via Homebrew on OSX Mavericks via the command `brew install homebrew/dupes/gdb`.  This error message pops up during install:

```
gdb requires special privileges to access Mach ports.
You will need to codesign the binary. For instructions, see:

  http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/info/bfd.info
Target /usr/local/share/info/bfd.info
is a symlink belonging to binutils. You can unlink it:
  brew unlink binutils

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite gdb

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run gdb

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/share/info/bfd.info -> /usr/local/Cellar/binutils/2.24/share/info/bfd.info
/usr/local/share/info/configure.info -> /usr/local/Cellar/binutils/2.24/share/info/configure.info
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/gdb/7.8: 46 files, 8.5M, built in 2.4 minutes
```

I've made sure to `chown` the folder `/usr/local`, but the same message still pops up.  Should I simply force the overwrite?  (Admittedly a Windows refugee so I don't have a complete picture of what's going on)

Answer (score 1):

The message is asking if `brew` should overwriting the documentation installed from `binutils` with the documentation installed from GDB, yes it's safe to overwrite those. It's generally safe to overwrite syslinks in `brew`, if it breaks something you can easily reinstall the package.